# Calling elisp code when awakening from sleep

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'd like to configure emacs a little differently when coming in over remote desktop. I can detect the rdp session, but I'd like to automatically run the function that checks when emacs wakes from sleep. I believe Windows issues a PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND event when awakening because of user activity -- is there a way to hook this from within emacs?

This would be for emacs 24.4 on Windows. Some code or a pointer to the right documentation would be great. I've looked but am not seeing anything -- maybe I'm not looking in the right place. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any hooks that are triggered in your situation, would it be possible to solve your situation using the [input focus hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Focus.html)?

Specifically, `focus-in-hook`.